# Wordpress Query Get all values for a key when match a value for another key

Tags: wordpress, metadata

The following query can get all values for a custom field key. collected from: http://goo.gl/94qw3

```
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
global $wpdb;
if( empty( $key ) )
    return;
$r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
    AND p.post_status = '%s' 
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
", $key, $status, $type ) );
return $r;
}
$my_var = get_meta_values( 'YOURKEY' );
```

I want to get all values for a key of "custom field B"
when match a value '2010' for a key of "custom field A".

Example:

I have 2 keys (2 costom Fields)

```
-------------------------
Movie Yr | Artist
---------------------------
2000     | Artist One   
2008     | Artist Two
2012     | Artist Three
         | Artist Four  
         | Artist Five
---------------------------
```

With the above query I can get the following list.

```
---------
Movie Yr
---------
2000    
2008    
2012    
---------
```

Now after I select value '2010' of the field "Movie Yr", I want to get a list of Artists. Not all artists but only those who are related with '2010'. Something like

```
---------
Artist
---------
Artist Two  
Artist Four
Artist Five
---------
```

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right here, insted of taking all the values you want to add another filter.
am i right?

if so - all you need is edit the SQL you get and add the filter you want.
this is your sql now:

```
SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'  AND p.post_status = '%s' AND p.post_type = '%s'
```

the `%s` is taking it's content from the variables that comes after:

```
$key, $status, $type
```

in that order.

in your case all you need to do is add the extra to the SQL query.

i would be happy to help you if you could just say what you want to do... your explanation is quite a mess.

Comment: if so, you can first run a sql for choosing the year. than - save it as a variable and than run an sql line "SELECT ALL WHERE" and add the year.
basic sql..